# What is this signal I've recorded?

Tags: packet, signal-identification

I've recorded what I believe packet radio signal. I tried few decoding tools on windows to no avail. Can anyone please have a look at this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8uVEQMPkrA) and tell me how to decode this signal or what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [POCSAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POCSAG) (Post Office Code Standardization Advisory Group). Typically used by numeric and text pagers.

Wikipedia also has a [sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pocsag-simple-stardado.ogg) of the audio that you can compare against.

Some have used [rtl_fm combined with multimon-ng](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45142) to decode POCSAG. A snippet from this site shows:

```
rtl_fm -N -o 4 -A lut -s 22050 -C -f 148.397M - | multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG512 -a POCSAG1200 -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'll have a go with multimon-ng!

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not familiar with the protocol nor have I tried to verify with a decoder, but the sync tones at the start of each transmission do not sound the same.

Answer (score 1):

PDW in windows will do just fine... no need to grab a linux box (unless you have one setup).
Certainly much easier than some rtl_fm/multimon setup.

http://www.discriminator.nl/pdw/index-en.html

Comment: Thanks very much for suggesting pdw, will give it a go (;